# Query 2nd SQL Server using the results from another (vb.net OleDbDataAdapter)

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have two **SQL Servers** that I must query.  Each has millions of records. I can not control them so I am unable to link them, and since they are so large, I can not read the entire tables in from both servers and join them.

Using **vb.net** `OleDbDataAdapter` I can successfully query the first and populate a `dataset.table(0)`

I am looking for a way to query the second server where the `CUSTOMER_ID` is the same as the rows in `dataset.table(0)`?

Any guidance would greatly be appreciated!  Thank you!

Comment: To clarify, are you talking about 2 SQL Server databases, each running on separate instances of SQL Server, or 2 SQL Server databases running on the same instance of SQL Server?

Comment: Completely separate server instances.

Comment: why are you using OleDb with SQL Server?

Comment: I don't have to use oledb. What do you recommend?

Comment: is it a one time query or something you'll do repeatedly?

Comment: @JustDennis, you should use SqlClient to access SQL Server from .NET.  It will perform better, especially for large SELECT queries.

Comment: can you iterate through your first table and build an SQL query with the WHERE clause: WHERE CUSTOMER_ID in (--list your customer id's here) or would it just be too long and unwieldy?

Comment: This is a query that will get run often.  Many times per hour to compare the two databases.  I will redo into SqlClient Dan.

Comment: As far as Where Clause (--list Id's) it would be far too long to iterate through.  There will be times (infrequent though) where the results are potentially 2.5 million records.  I'll most likely do a SQLDataReader on the MASTER Database and move through the results comparing.  My aim is to do this with as little overhead to the SQL Servers as possible.